Arduino Code to determine if we are in DST or not
I am writing C code for an ESP32C3, so an Arduino type piece of hardware. There is no internal clock, so to get the time I talking to an NTP server on the internet.
I am also talking to a weather server to get the weather locally, including the sunrise and sunset.
Now all is well, except the fact that the weather server doesn't seem to know about daylight saving times, so it gives me values that are one hour out.
So I wrote this routine to try to figure out if I need to adjust the answer for sunrise/sunset [its in Arduino C]
Here is the definition, yes I am in Europe.

Daylight saving time always starts on the second Sunday in March and
ends on the first Sunday in November in the United States. This
contrasts with the UK and European Union, where summer time begins on
the last Sunday in March and ends on the last Sunday in October.

char dayName[10];
char dayMonth[2];
char monthYear[2];

strftime(dayName,64,"%A", &timeinfo); // day of the week
strftime(dayMonth,64,"%d", &timeinfo); // day of the month
strftime(monthYear,64,"%B", &timeinfo); // month of the year

if (!strcmp(dayName, "Sunday")) {
  if (atoi(monthYear) == 10) {
    if (atoi(dayMonth) > 31 - 7) {
    // last Sunday of the month October, DST = false
      DST = false;
    }
  }
  if (atoi(monthYear) == 3) {
    if (atoi(dayMonth) > 31 - 7) {
      // last Sunday of the month March, DST = false
      DST = true;
    }
  }
}

Get the time with this routine
const char* ntpServer = "ch.pool.ntp.org";
const long  gmtOffset_sec = 3600;
const int   daylightOffset_sec = 0;

void getTime() {
  configTime(gmtOffset_sec, daylightOffset_sec, ntpServer);

  if(!getLocalTime(&timeinfo)){
    //Serial.println("Failed to obtain time");
    return;
  }
}

Obviously I don't set the daylight variable before I get the time because I don't know if I am in DST. Chicken and Egg.
Questions:

Does this code look sane?
Is there a better way of doing this? Remember it isn't a computer, its an ESP32C3; so you don't get date for example- it has no idea what the date/time is.


if (dayName == "Sunday") { --> you want if (!strcmp(dayName, "Sunday")), you can not compares strings with ==, also, why are you testing the same thing twice?

Thanks David; I think your code is right, mine is wrong I will fix it

You are welcome @user3069232, notice that you forget the !  in !strcmp(...) in your edit.

But the day should be Sunday; I want Sunday? Using an ! says not true? did I misunderstand that too?

strcmp returns 0 when the strings are equal.

@user3069232 How is your time zone determined?

Added a little more code to make it clearer,

If would seem that your code attempts to check if it is running on the day when time changes, not if it is running during DST or not. Or if it's any other day it leaves the boolean with an indeterminate value. That's buggy and not useful at all. Instead the code should check if the date is within a certain interval. Write down what the code should be doing in plain English on pen & paper, then implement it.

Lundin; I like your train of thought. Yes, it does and Yes your suggestion is a very good one! Thank you! I will think about it some more!


Does this code look sane?

No.

DST is not assigned at all under most timeonfo values.

Rather than convert struct tm *timeinfo to a string and then to a value, simply use the corresponding member of struct tm.


// if (atoi(monthYear) == 10)
int month = timeinfo.tm_mon + 1
if (month == 10) 



Is there a better way of doing this, (?)

First try accessing the .tm_isdst member after calling getLocalTime(&timeinfo).
DST = timeinfo.tm_isds > 0;


Google tells me, "The value of tm_isdst is positive if Daylight Saving Time is in effect, 0 if It is not, and negative if the information is not available. When I query it I get 0, which given it is November is as I understand it correct.  So I can do the whole thing with one line? Yes??

It looks good ,but you could just reduce 64 to 10 for dayName, and 30 for dayMonth and monthYear so you could optimize the storage (remember this is an ESP wich is not a very powerful chip so optimizing the memory usage is necessary),and also you could add a log statement to keep you informed for example ESP_LOGI(TAG, "DST: %s", DST ? "true" : "false");.

I took the advice of Lundin to heart and, together with the other suggestions here, rewrote the whole thing.
void getTime() {
  configTime(gmtOffset_sec, daylightOffset_sec, ntpServer);

  if(!getLocalTime(&timeinfo)){
    Serial.println("Failed to obtain time");
  return;

  }
}

struct tm* getday(char * str) {
  memset((void *) &tm, 0, sizeof(tm));
  if (strptime(str, "%d-%m-%Y", &tm) != NULL) {
    time_t t = mktime(&tm);
    if (t >= 0) {
      return localtime(&t);
    }
  }
  return NULL;
}

int rtnday(int month) {
struct tm* nday;
char sday[10];
for (int day=25; day<32; day++) {
  sprintf(sday,"%d-%d-%d",day,month,timeinfo.tm_year);
  nday = getday(sday);
  if (nday->tm_wday == 0) {
    return nday->tm_yday + 1;
  }
}
  return -1;
}

dday = rtnday(10);
eday = rtnday(3);

if (timeinfo.tm_yday > dday || timeinfo.tm_yday < eday) {
  DST = true;
}

It now works on the number of days past, so 31st October is day 301 and the 31st March is day 91. The routine getday returns the wday+yday for seven days prior to these. The rtnday routine returns the "yday" that will be a Sunday counting back from those values.
Finally I set the daylightsavings variable for the whole range, so days after the last Sunday of October 31st and days prior to the last Sunday of March 31st.
